# i am getting bad input in line 8. I am able to run it in Atom but its showing an error in py4e site which i have to use in my coursera

Tags: python, coursera-api

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:

    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        numm = int(num)
        if largest is None:
            largest = numm
        elif numm>largest:
            largest = numm
        if smallest is None:
            smallest = numm
        elif smallest>numm:
            smallest=numm
    except:
        if num == "done" :
            break
        else :
            print('Invalid input')

print("Maximum", largest)
print("Minimum", smallest)
```

This is my first time using stack overflow so pls excuse my errors

Comment: Are you sure `done` is the proper input to end the numbers?

Comment: Do you get the full traceback? Which line is the error happening on?

Comment: @Barmar yes, it working when i use atom and cmd but it showing bad input for the line where i have given the first if statement

Comment: @Barmar i think it was a bug or something because i retyped it and got it correct